# How to get all profile ids with ZendGData Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, zend-framework2, zend-gdata

I am using ZendGData library for ZF2.

I tried to get account`s data, but there is no data about profiles.

```
$email = $this->config['email'];
$password = $this->config['password'];

$service = \ZendGData\Analytics::AUTH_SERVICE_NAME;
$client = \ZendGData\ClientLogin::getHttpClient($email, $password, $service);
$analytics = new \ZendGData\Analytics($client);

print_r($analytics->getAccountFeed());
```

How can I get list of profiles (or profile ids) for my account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found solution:

```
$email = $this->config['email'];
$password = $this->config['password'];

$service = \ZendGData\Analytics::AUTH_SERVICE_NAME;
$client = \ZendGData\ClientLogin::getHttpClient($email, $password, $service);
$analytics = new \ZendGData\Analytics($client);

$profileResult = $analytics->getDataFeed($analytics->newAccountQuery()->profiles());

$profileIds = array();
/**
 * @var \ZendGData\Analytics\DataEntry $dataBit
 */
 foreach ($profileResult as $dataBit) {
     /**
       * @var \ZendGData\App\Extension\Element $element
       */
     foreach ($dataBit->getExtensionElements() as $element) {
         $attributes = $element->getExtensionAttributes();
         if ($attributes['name']['value']=='ga:profileId') {
             $profileIds[] = $attributes['value']['value'];
         }
    }
}
```